# Android MediaCodec api compress video

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am building an app where i need to compress video before uploading it to server. I have tried ffmpeg4android(https://github.com/chloette/ffmpeg4android) which is very heavy in size. Its increasing 20MB size of my app.

I tried MediaCodec android api, which is not working as expected.

Can anyone have working code example for compressing a video with MediaCodec android api?

**Update:**
Yes looking for MP4 containers.

Comment: Are you using MediaMuxer to wrap MediaCodec's H.264 output as a .mp4?

Comment: My input video is .mp4 and Yes i am using MediaMuxer, its giving me wrong duration of output .mp4 video.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague question since you do not specify a codec or file container, but assuming you are interested in H.264 codecs and MP4 containers there are a lot of examples [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/). Specifically, you will probably be interested in [CameraToMpegTest.java](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt).

Note that even though the requirements are stated as Android 4.3, MediaCodec support is poor until Android 5.1.